# Add text in rect svg and append it to arc in donut chart

Tags: d3.js, donut-chart

I wanted to add labels to each arc in donut chart. I've added by taking the centroid of each arc and adding, but somehow it is not adding in correct position. I can't figure it out so I need some help regarding it. I've added my code in codepen. The link is [here](https://codepen.io/wittybutterfly/pen/NWxvqjg?editors=1010).
My donut should look like this.

[image]

Sample code is:

```
svg.selectAll(".dataText")
.data(data_ready)
.enter()
.each(function (d) {
  var centroid = arc.centroid(d);
  d3.select(this)
    .append('rect')
    .attr("class", "dataBG_" + d.data.value.label)
    .attr('x', (centroid[0]) - 28)
    .attr('y', (centroid[1]) - 5)
    .attr('rx', '10px')
    .attr('ry', '10px')
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .style('fill', d.data.value.color)
    .style("opacity", 1.0);
  d3.select(this)
    .append('text')
    .attr("class", "dataText_" + d.data.value.label)
    .style('fill', 'white')
    .style("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("dx", (centroid[0]) - 7)
    .attr("dy", centroid[1] + 7)
    .text(Math.round((d.data.value.value)) + "%");
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a little unclear to me precisely what you're after here, since the codepen you sent looks different in terms of the underlying data. Are you trying to have the labels at the very edge of the radius? Or, are you trying to get collision detection implemented for the labels? I guess I'm trying to figure what the priority is on your end.

Comment: I'm trying to add the labels at the edge of the radius as well as at the centroid. @scrollex

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the "bad" state on codepen and the desired state is that in the one you don't like, you take the centroid and then you center your text on it. The centroid of a thick arc is the midpoint of the arc that runs from the midpoint of one line-segment cap to the other. This is roughly "center of mass" of the shape if it had some finite thickness and were a physical object. I don't think it's what you want. What you want is the midpoint of the outer arc. There's no function to generate it, but it's easy enough to calculate. Also, I think you want to justify your text differently for arcs whose text-anchor point is on the left hand of the chart from those on the right half. I'm going copy your code and modify it, with comments explaining.

```
// for some reason I couldn't get Math.Pi to work in d3.js, so
// I'm just going to calculate it once here in the one-shot setup
var piValue = Math.acos(-1);
// also, I'm noting the inner radius here and calculating the
// the outer radius (this is similar to what you do in codepen.)
var innerRadius = 40
var thickness = 30
var outerRadius = innerRadius + thickness

svg.selectAll(".dataText")
.data(data_ready)
.enter()
.each(function (d) {
  // I'm renaming "centroid" to "anchor - just a    
  // point that relates to where you want to put
  // the label, regardless of what it means geometrically.

  // no more call to arc.centroid
  // var centroid = arc.centroid(d);

  // calculate the angle halfway between startAngle and
  // endAngle. We can just average them because the convention
  // seems to be that angles always increase, even if you
  // if you pass the 2*pi/0 angle, and that endAngle
  // is always greater than startAngle. I subtract piValue
  // before dividing by 2 because in "real" trigonometry, the
  // convention is that a ray that points in the 0 valued
  // angles are measured against the positive x-axis, which
  // is angle 0. In D3.pie conventions, the 0-angle points upward
  // along the y-axis. Subtracting pi/2 to all angles before
  // doing any trigonometry fixes that, because x and y
  // are handled normally.

  var bisectAngle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle - piValue) / 2.0
  var anchor = [ outerRadius * Math.cos(bisectAngle), outerRadius * Math.sin(bisectAngle) ];

  d3.select(this)
    .append('rect')
    .attr("class", "dataBG_" + d.data.value.label)

    // now if you stopped and didn't change anything more, you'd
    // have something kind of close to what you want, but to get
    // it closer, you want the labels to "swing out" from the 
    // from the circle - to the left on the left half of the
    // the chart and to the right on the right half. So, I'm
    // replacing your code with fixed offsets to code that is
    // sensitive to which side we're on. You probably also want
    // to replace the constants with something related to the 
    // the dynamic size of the label background, but I leave
    // that as an "exercise for the reader".

    // .attr('x', anchor[0] - 28)
    // .attr('y', anchor[1] - 5)

    .attr('x', anchor[0] < 0 ? anchor[0] - 48 : anchor[0] - 2)
    .attr('y', anchor[1] - 10

    .attr('rx', '10px')
    .attr('ry', '10px')
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .style('fill', d.data.value.color)
    .style("opacity", 1.0);
  d3.select(this)
    .append('text')
    .attr("class", "dataText_" + d.data.value.label)
    .style('fill', 'white')
    .style("font-size", "11px")

    // changing the text centering code to match the box
    // box-centering code above. Again, rather than constants,
    // you're probably going to want something a that
    // that adjusts to the size of the background box

    // .attr("dx", anchor[0] - 7)
    // .attr("dy", anchor[1] + 7)

    .attr("dx", anchor[0] < 0 ? anchor[0] - 28 : anchor[0] + 14)
    .attr("dy", anchor[1] + 4)
    .text(Math.round((d.data.value.value)) + "%");
});
```

I tested. this code on your codepen example. I apologize if I affected your example for everyone - I'm not familiar with codepen and I don't know the collaboration rules. This is all just meant by way of suggestion, it can be made a lot more efficient with a few tweaks, but I wanted to keep it parallel to make it clear what I was changing and why. Hope this gives you some good ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation. It was very helpful. @cycollins

Comment: @Max ...are you being sarcastic with the "brief"? :-) ... I have a tendency to make very verbose answers. It's just that I try to make them with the issues called out the way I'd like to read them. Kind of the Golden Rule of answering.

Comment: What I said about the thick arc centroid above is not correct. Consider an arc made of "wire" - something with linear density. The center of mass of that object would be inside the concavity along the radial axis. For a thick arc, I'd have to do the integral, but to get an intuition for it, as the angle subtended goes down, the arc more closely approximates a quadrilateral, for which the centroid is the center. As the angle goes up, it looks more like the wire, so the centroid moves toward the center along the radius, possibly inbound of the inner radius. Even worse for labels.

Comment: However, I did think of a way to start with the centroid and end up with the point you want at the mid-point of the outer radius. The centroid is definitely on the same radius as the outer midpoint. All you have to do is take the length of the radius at the centroid, and scale the coordinates by the ratio of that length to the outer radius value. The advantage to this approach over my method above is that it doesn't require any conventions about positive-valued, increasing angle stops and starts. I don't know for a fact that those conventions are enforced or just evident in the examples.